# Touch detection throughout the application

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm developing an application with SwiftUI and I need to know when the user touches the screen throughout my application even if he's using buttons, sliders, etc. in subviews.

I have tried to implement this in my main view:

```
.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({ _ in
           print("tap")
}))
```

It seems to work even when I use buttons in subviews, but when I use sliders I don't get the information that the user is touching the screen.

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Because sliding finger movements are not taps!?

Comment: I agree but I tried to implement simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded and I can't do anything else on my app, I mean I can't tap on buttons, etc.